# VBA nested FOR loop works for first occurence but ignores the following ones

Tags: excel, vba, loops, iteration

I am struggling with a FOR loop nested in another one to check each row of a table horizontally before moving to the next row.

Goal:
I need my code to ignore all cells with a 0 value and do some basic (irrelevant) manipulations with the non zero cells.

Problem:
My code works for the first non zero cell of the row but ignores all the other ones both in the same row and the following ones.

Code basic structure:

- FOR loop 1: goes from a row to the next;
- FOR loop 2: (nested in loop 1) goes from a cell in the row to the next;
- IF THEN : (nested in loop 2) checks for non zero cells and does the manipulation

I've tried to reorganise loops, to reverse the IF Then structure to first ignore the zero cells but then I can't find the way to go to the next iteration of loop 2.

```
Dim RNB As Long, ROutput As Integer, VBAR As Integer, VBAC As Integer, i As Long, j As Long


'RNB        = amounts of rows to check in input table;
'ROutput    = the row number of the output table where to paste the desired values;
'VBAR       = row number of the first cell to check in the Input table;
'VBAC       = column number of the first cell to check in the Input table;
'i          = the counting variable for the vertical FOR loop; and
'j          = the counting variable for the horizontal FOR loop.

'Vertical parent FOR loop
For i = 1 To RNB
         
'Horizontal nested FOR loop: cells with a null value are ignored and the remaining ones are copied in the Output worksheet, in the first empty row available

         For j = 1 To 11
        
            If Cells(i + [2] - 1, [2] + 2 + j).Value <> 0 Then
            
                'Copy/paste of the value of the identified cell and save the row number for the remaining information to add in next steps
                [Input1].Select
                Cells(i + [VBA_Row].Value - 1, [Segment].Value + 2 + j).Copy
               
     '[Irrelevant code that actually works perfectly for the first iteration (I will display it if necessary)]

                
            Else: End If
        Next j
   Next i
```

No error messages displayed.

The code does the job for the first iteration but typically if the 2 first cells of row 1 are not equal to zero: the code does the job for cell 1, ignores cell 2 and goes to the next row to ignore all other cells.

Comment: You definetely should add `debug.print` [Segment].Value and [VBA_Row].Value to see what values are stored.

Comment: Thank you very much Mamoun Benghezal for your advice: both items are named cells in Excel storing the integer value "2" for coordinates that remain constant throughout the code execution. I replaced them in the code as such in [].

Comment: Hi Chris Neilsen. Thank you for your answer. It is definitely possible that I'm mistaken on their nature. I expect these terms to store an integer value based on a named cell in Excel with this syntax [Named_Cell].value. These values are cell coordinates (integers) in order for the macro to know where to start checking all cells, based on the intial input table which format can vary: the user is supposed to set the values of these terms before running the macro. What did I actually do?

Comment: Could you post the whole code and also show how you are calling it? Might be an idea to explain what the 'irrelevant' manipulations are because, well , they might actually be relevant.:)